# Combining MySQL row with previous row if field is empty

Tags: mysql, csv, where-clause, rows

I'm trying to take a MySQL database with descriptions spread over multiple lines (which was imported from a  CSV file) and combine rows where everything but the description is blank in order to complete the description fields.

Starting with this:

```
ID    PLU     Description
100   1       Line 1
101           Line 2
102   2       Line 3
103   3       Line 4
105           Line 5
106           Line 6
```

Trying to turn it into this:

```
ID    PLU     Description
100   1       Line 1 Line 2
102   2       Line 3
103   3       Line 4 Line 5 Line 6
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: 
To add some background, I get a price list sent to be formatted as a CSV, and there's unfortunately nothing I can do to change the incoming format. If the description of an item is too long it's continued in the next cell down, leaving numerous lines that contain nothing but description. I'm looking to come up with a way to append the description lines that are on their own to the description that is a part of a valid row. If there's an easier way to do this while the data is still a CSV I'm definitely open to that as well.

Comment: Why are the PLU's blank, this is bad data almost by definition.

Comment: It sounds like you can do something quick and simple before import or on import. Can you share the original format? I am just thinking out loud, if you get the csv file opens correctly in excel (excel is pretty good at this) and just import the right format. I think this is much better than writing complex sql code to get the full description.

Comment: @NKD I added some background to try to better explain what I'm doing.

Comment: @Ar3n can you provide and example of the csv format (possibly 2 records)? I'm hoping to get a sample of the csv version to see if I can help you think of a way to cleanse it before/upon load. It is best to void bad data integrity in db.

Answer (score 0):

See my original comment, but this might work:

```
SET @prevPLU := 0;
SET @firstID := 0;
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID
, @prevPLU := IF(PLU='',@prevPLU, PLU) AS actualPLU
, GROUP_CONCAT(Description ORDER BY ID SEPARATOR ' ') AS Description
FROM theTable
GROUP BY actualPLU
;
```

Comment: I added some background (in response to your original comment) to the op.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to this:

First, you need to fill in the missing PLU values. As others have said in the comments, you should do this as you load the data if you possibly can. If you *must* use SQL for that, here's how (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4aaf/6/0)  Let me emphasize that this is a ***nasty hack*** because it violates the declarative way SQL is supposed to work.

```
SELECT ID, 
       CASE WHEN PLU IS NOT NULL
             THEN @prev:=PLU
             ELSE @prev END PLU, 
       Description
  FROM tbl
  JOIN (SELECT @prev:=NULL) init
 ORDER BY ID
```

Next, you summarize this subquery / virtual table with GROUP BY. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4aaf/9/0)

```
 SELECT MIN(ID) ID,
        PLU,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Description ORDER BY Description SEPARATOR ' ') Description
  FROM (
       SELECT ID, 
              CASE WHEN PLU IS NOT NULL
                   THEN @prev:=PLU
                   ELSE @prev END PLU, 
              Description
         FROM tbl
         JOIN (SELECT @prev:=NULL) init
        ORDER BY ID
       ) t
 GROUP BY PLU
```